# JPA: how to fetch records of distinct column :

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

How do I write a query to fetch records which is distinct in one column and desc order in another column.

I was able to fetch the records using the following statement.

```
  select * from
 (select * from t1 
  where id=14 
  order by ttimestamp desc) as h 
  group by hnumber 
  order by ttimestamp desc
```

But when I tried the same in JPA.

```
  SELECT m from 
  (SELECT m from t1 m 
   WHERE m.user = :user 
   ORDER BY m.tTimestamp DESC) as h 
  GROUP BY m.hNumber 
  ORDER BY m.tTimestamp DESC
```

I got an error saying syntax error.

```
  Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT m from (SELECT m from t1 m WHERE m.user = :user ORDER BY m.tTimestamp DESC) as h GROUP BY m.hNumber ORDER BY m.tTimestamp DESC]. 
   The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.
   An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
   The query contains a malformed ending.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Leo I tried this as well.. SELECT m from 
  (SELECT n from t1 n 
   WHERE n.user = :user 
   ORDER BY n.tTimestamp DESC) as h 
  GROUP BY m.hNumber 
  ORDER BY m.tTimestamp DESC and it did not work.

Comment: if your subquery is h, why are you selecting m?

Comment: @Leo Could you please suggest me the correct way of implementing this query. I tried this "SELECT m from (SELECT n from t1 n WHERE n.user = :user ORDER BY n.tTimestamp DESC) m GROUP BY m.hNumber ORDER BY m.tTimestamp DESC" but failed.

Comment: TBH I don't understand why you need to do a subselect in your statement, the exterior GROUP BY invalidates the inner ORDER BY. Do you want to retrieve the latest entry for each ID or for a specific ID?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Yes, I want to retrieve records for each ID which has max timestamp from t1 table.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296347/jpa-select-latest-instance-for-each-item) works for you.