# JPA select only the most recent dates per item

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

So I have a jpa database query that works, and returns all the SiteBmdfBusinessDay's from that table and relates them to their corresponding SiteBmdf by joining on their ID columns. What I want to do is, instead of getting all of the SiteBmdfBusinessDay's, I just want to get the ones with the most recent businessDay.

Here is the SiteBmdfBusinessDay class...

```
@Entity
public class SiteBmdfBusinessDay extends BaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private SiteBmdf siteBmdf;
private DateTime businessDay;
private Long failedCount;
private DateTime lastSuccessfulBusinessDay;
private DateTime lastSuccessfulFullBusinessDay;
private Ticket ticket;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "site_bmdf_business_day_site_bmdf_business_day_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "site_bmdf_business_day_site_bmdf_business_day_id_seq", sequenceName = "site_bmdf_business_day_site_bmdf_business_day_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "site_bmdf_business_day_id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "site_bmdf_id")
public SiteBmdf getSiteBmdf() {
    return siteBmdf;
}

public void setSiteBmdf(SiteBmdf siteBmdf) {
    this.siteBmdf = siteBmdf;
}

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "UTC"), @Parameter(name = "javaZone", value = "UTC") })
public DateTime getBusinessDay() {
    return businessDay;
}

public void setBusinessDay(DateTime businessDay) {
    this.businessDay = businessDay;
}

public Long getFailedCount() {
    return failedCount;
}

public void setFailedCount(Long count) {
    this.failedCount = count;
}

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "UTC"), @Parameter(name = "javaZone", value = "UTC") })
public DateTime getLastSuccessfulBusinessDay() {
    return lastSuccessfulBusinessDay;
}

public void setLastSuccessfulBusinessDay(DateTime lastSuccessfulBusinessDay) {
    this.lastSuccessfulBusinessDay = lastSuccessfulBusinessDay;
}

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "UTC"), @Parameter(name = "javaZone", value = "UTC") })
public DateTime getLastSuccessfulFullBusinessDay() {
    return lastSuccessfulFullBusinessDay;
}

public void setLastSuccessfulFullBusinessDay(DateTime lastSuccessfulFullBusinessDay) {
    this.lastSuccessfulFullBusinessDay = lastSuccessfulFullBusinessDay;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
public Ticket getTicket() {
    return ticket;
}

public void setTicket(Ticket ticket) {
    this.ticket = ticket;
}
}
```

And the SiteBmdf class...

```
@Entity
public class SiteBmdf extends BaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String site;
private Long failureCount;
private Set<SiteBmdfBusinessDay> businessDays;
private List<SiteBmdfNote> notes;
private Resolution resolution; 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "site_bmdf_site_bmdf_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "site_bmdf_site_bmdf_id_seq", sequenceName = "site_bmdf_site_bmdf_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "site_bmdf_id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSite() {
    return site;
}

public void setSite(String site) {
    this.site = site;
}

@Transient
public Long getFailureCount() {
    return failureCount;
}

public void setFailureCount(Long failureCount) {
    this.failureCount = failureCount;
}

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "siteBmdf", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<SiteBmdfBusinessDay> getBusinessDays() {
    return this.businessDays;
}

public void setBusinessDays(Set<SiteBmdfBusinessDay> businessDays) {
    this.businessDays = businessDays;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "siteBmdf", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<SiteBmdfNote> getNotes() {
    Collections.sort(notes);
    return notes;
}

public void setNotes(List<SiteBmdfNote> notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "resolutionId")
public Resolution getResolution() {
    return resolution;
}

public void setResolution(Resolution resolution) {
    this.resolution = resolution;
}
}
```

And here is the current query method....

```
@Override
public PageImpl<SiteBmdfBusinessDay> bmdfSitePaged(UiBuildCriteria criteria) {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<SiteBmdfBusinessDay> query = builder.createQuery(SiteBmdfBusinessDay.class);
    Root<SiteBmdfBusinessDay> root = query.from(SiteBmdfBusinessDay.class);

    if (!criteria.getSearch().getPredicateObject().isEmpty()) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = predicateBuilderService.buildPredicates(builder, root, criteria.getSearch());
        query.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
    }

    query.select(root);

    builder.max(root.<Long>get("businessDay"));

    // get the count for PageImpl
    Long total = this.count(criteria);

    // Set the order by
    List<CustomSort> defaultSorts = new ArrayList<CustomSort>(
            Arrays.asList(
                new CustomSort("businessDay", Boolean.TRUE),
                new CustomSort("siteBmdf.site", Boolean.FALSE)
            ));

    List<Order> orders = sortOrderBuilderService.buildSort(builder, root, criteria.getSort(), defaultSorts);

    query.orderBy(orders);

    List<SiteBmdfBusinessDay> content = entityManager.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(criteria.getPagination().getStart())
            .setMaxResults(criteria.getPagination().getNumber()).getResultList();

    return new PageImpl<>(content, criteria.getPageRequest(), total);
}
```

So like I said, the current results are just all the items in the SiteBmdfBusinessDay table with their corresponding SiteBmdfs. I would like only the SiteBmdfBusinessDays with the most recent businessDay for each site.

For instance, if I have the table site_bmdf_business_day:

```
site_bmdf_business_day_id | site_bmdf_id | business_day
1                         | 1            |  6/1/2011
2                         | 2            |  6/1/2011
3                         | 1            |  6/6/2011
4                         | 3            |  6/6/2011
```

I would only want to display:

```
site_bmdf_business_day_id | site_bmdf_id | business_day
2                         | 2            |  6/1/2011
3                         | 1            |  6/6/2011
4                         | 3            |  6/6/2011
```

I know i will need something along the lines of builder.max(root.get("businessDay")) but i'm not sure how to implement it.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296347/jpa-select-latest-instance-for-each-item) is similar, but not exactly what I am looking for as all of the answers are in SQL and I need something in jpa here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these type of queries, I typically boil it down to sql (without pagination and other limitations), and then reverse construct it into a querybuilder.  It makes for cleaner code IMO.  What you're looking for is something like

```
select a.* from SiteBmdfBusinessDay a 
inner join 
( select site_bmdf_id, max (business_day) as business_day 
  from SiteBmdfBusinessDay group by site_bmdf_id ) b 
on (a.site_bmdf_id = b.site_bmdf_id) and (a.business_day = b.business_day)
```

This assumes that there's at most one entry per day, per site_bmdf_id.

This is, as far as I know, not doable as a builder, however, you can put this as a create query and it works just fine (because the result is just a normal entity.)  However, it's a very performance prohibitive query, assuming you have a decent amount of data.  Unless you have a small data set, it's probably better to just take it all, and then programmatically filter out duplicates (which you should be able to do in O(n) time.)

Comment: Well that SQL definitely works, so thank you for that! Though, I am not going to mark this as solved just yet, in case anyone has an idea that works as a builder, which is what I really need. The thing here is that while, this specific data set may not get too large, I would like to use this implementation in places where the table may be close to 1M rows, so I definitely cannot pull the whole set and parse through it.

Comment: Alas, my boss likes the original outcome anyway so I am marking this as solved!