# JPA CriteriaQuery Query latest data of each entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a project that uses SpringBoot 1.5.9 (can't change version).

I have these entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
public class DataEntity extends Timestampable {

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "data_timestamp")
    private ZonedDateTime dataTimestamp;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private DataTypeEntity type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private AssetEntity asset;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "data_type")
public class DataTypeEntity extends Timestampable {

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

I have this working SQL query (under PostgreSQL), to retrieve the latest data per asset ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783249/5194836)):

```
SELECT * FROM data d1
JOIN (
  SELECT max(data_timestamp) as newest, asset_id FROM data
  GROUP BY asset_id
) d2
ON d1.data_timestamp = d2.newest AND d1.asset_id = d2.asset_id
WHERE d1.type_id IN (
  SELECT id FROM data_type
  WHERE name = 'ELECTRICITY_CONSUMPTION'
);
```

I want to translate this query into a JPA CriteriaQuery.
Is there a way to do so, or do I need to use a @SubSelect annotation on a specific entity ?

Thanks for reading this !

**(UGLY) SOLUTION**

I ended up using a database View, with a SubSelect.
I've split my DataEntity into 2 entities :

1. One to manipulate the datas
2. Anoher that is a view and used only to retrieve the latest data

Base class :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractDataEntity extends Timestampable {

    @Column(name = "value")
    protected String value;

    ...

}
```

Manipulation class :

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idgen", sequenceName = "data_seq")
@Table(name = "data")
@DiscriminatorValue("DataEntity")
public class DataEntity extends AbstractDataEntity {
    @Override
    public DataEntity setValue(String value) {
        super.setValue(value);
        return this;
    }

   ...
}
```

View class :

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idgen", sequenceName = "view_data_last_seq")
@DiscriminatorValue("LastDataView")
@Subselect(
    "SELECT * FROM data d1 " +
    "JOIN ( " +
    "  SELECT max(d.data_timestamp) as newest, d.asset_id, d.type_id FROM data d " +
    "  WHERE d.parameter_id IS NULL " +
    "  GROUP BY d.asset_id, d.type_id" +
    ") d2 " +
    "ON d1.data_timestamp = d2.newest " +
    "  AND d1.asset_id = d2.asset_id " +
    "  AND d1.type_id = d2.type_id"
)
public class LastDataView extends AbstractDataEntity {
}
```

Even if I find this solution ugly, it may help others !

Comment: I don't think you can do subqueries in select statements in JPQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL [does not support](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/3.0.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries) subqueries on `FROM` or `JOIN`. Only in `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses. Eclipse Link, [starting from 2.4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause), have support for subqueries on the `FROM` clause.

As [every Criteria is converted to the JPQL](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-query-plan-cache/), it's not possible to use Criteria to do what you want.